# Choosing file format for image editing in PHP

Tags: php, image

I need to load several images from files, render them into one image (draw them onto each other, layer by layer) and then output the result to the browser as a JPEG. This should be done as efficiently as possible. The images are about 1366x720 pixels large.

**My question is, what should the initial format of the files be?**

If i use JPEGs, i'll need to
1. Load the images
2. Decode into raw data
3. Draw them upon eachother
4. Encode into JPEG and output

Is there a format, which won't need to be decoded? Would that make any significant difference?

Comment: Nope, that won’t make any significant difference. Most important thing when manipulating images with PHP is how much RAM is needed – and that depends on the image pixel sizes, not on how they might be compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All image formats need to be decoded, I guess your question really is, are there formats which has simple decoding? Yes, the Portable Pixmap format (ppm) from the PNM format family is one of the simplest image format there is. Here's an example:

```
P3
# The P3 means colors are in ASCII, then 3 columns and 2 rows, 
# then 255 for max color, then RGB triplet 
3 2 
255 
255 0   0      0    255 0     0   0   255 
255 255 0      255 255 255    0   0   0
```

which produces this image:

[image: alt]

However, simplicity of the file fomat really shouldn't be an issue because you really should be using an image library. In PHP, gd is available in most web hosting.

In any case, whichever file format you choose, because you'll be editing the image, stay away from lossy formats like JPEG. The image quality of a lossy formats gets worse each time it's saved and therefore unsuitable for intermediate format. They're fine for final output though. For intermediate formats, pick a lossless format like PNG or BMP or PPM.

Comment: I am more concerned with the speed of reading the files into memory. I understand that after a JPEG (or any format) is loaded into memory to be edited, it's basically just a bitmap. So i was wondering if some formats are loaded/decoded faster.

Comment: @OlavKokovkin: Without knowing the image and the platform you're running the code on, that's impossible to answer. If efficiency is your concern then you'll just have to measure it. The binary PPM format (P6 PPM) can be decoded more efficiently than ASCII PPM (P3 PPM). A compressed format can sometimes be more efficient than uncompressed though, as there's less data to read from disk; using simple compression like RLE could sufficiently reduce the amount of data that have to be read from disk while having practically no decode performance loss. You just had to measure.